# PHP: Check if FORM values are empty

Tags: php

I'm checking to make sure all incoming `$_POST` values are not empty. is using isEmpty the best method. This is a second check prior to db entry, I'm already using a jquery form validate

```
if (!isEmpty($_POST['add']) || ($_POST['add']['type'] == 2 && !isEmpty($_POST['cpl']))):
    // insert into db
else:
    header("Location: /?req=register");
    exit();
endif;
```

Comment: I think you are thinking of `!empty($_POST['add'])` http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: @Moak thanks, not sure what i was thinking when I typed that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
if (isset($_POST['add']) AND $_POST['add'] != '')
```

you can chcek in many way using also NULL

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, as [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) (no such thing as `isEmpty`) considers some values as empty.

> The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

You can just use `if($_POST['add'] <> '') ...`

Comment: thanks, what should I use instead of !Empty to check if the values and nothing in them?

Comment: You can just use `if($_POST['add'] <> '') ...`

Comment: something like this would work fine correct?
`if ($_POST['add'] != '' || ($_POST['add']['type'] == 2 && $_POST['cpl'] != '')):`

Comment: @njk Wouldn't `if ($_POST['add'] <> '')` throw a php notice if it is undefined?

Comment: @Antony I'm assuming it would be defined and depends on the error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `isset` to see whether the variable is set or not. This will help in radio and checkbox if you have not selected.

```
 (isset($_POST['add']) && $_POST['add'] != '')
```

You can also use `!empty($_POST['add'])`